# Keras U-Net weighted loss implementation

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, image-segmentation

I'm trying to separate close objects as was shown in the U-Net paper ([here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.04597.pdf)). For this, one generates weight maps which can be used for pixel-wise losses. The following code describes the network I use from [this](https://jaidevd.github.io/posts/weighted-loss-functions-for-instance-segmentation/) blog post.

```py
x_train_val = # list of images (imgs, 256, 256, 3)
y_train_val = # list of masks (imgs, 256, 256, 1)
y_weights = # list of weight maps (imgs, 256, 256, 1) according to the blog post 
# visual inspection confirms the correct calculation of these maps

# Blog posts' loss function
def my_loss(target, output):
    return - tf.reduce_sum(target * output,
                           len(output.get_shape()) - 1)

# Standard Unet model from blog post
_epsilon = tf.convert_to_tensor(K.epsilon(), np.float32)

def make_weighted_loss_unet(input_shape, n_classes):
    ip = L.Input(shape=input_shape)
    weight_ip = L.Input(shape=input_shape[:2] + (n_classes,))

    conv1 = L.Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(ip)
    conv1 = L.Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv1)
    conv1 = L.Dropout(0.1)(conv1)
    mpool1 = L.MaxPool2D()(conv1)

    conv2 = L.Conv2D(128, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(mpool1)
    conv2 = L.Conv2D(128, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv2)
    conv2 = L.Dropout(0.2)(conv2)
    mpool2 = L.MaxPool2D()(conv2)

    conv3 = L.Conv2D(256, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(mpool2)
    conv3 = L.Conv2D(256, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv3)
    conv3 = L.Dropout(0.3)(conv3)
    mpool3 = L.MaxPool2D()(conv3)

    conv4 = L.Conv2D(512, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(mpool3)
    conv4 = L.Conv2D(512, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv4)
    conv4 = L.Dropout(0.4)(conv4)
    mpool4 = L.MaxPool2D()(conv4)

    conv5 = L.Conv2D(1024, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(mpool4)
    conv5 = L.Conv2D(1024, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv5)
    conv5 = L.Dropout(0.5)(conv5)

    up6 = L.Conv2DTranspose(512, 2, strides=2, kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(conv5)
    conv6 = L.Concatenate()([up6, conv4])
    conv6 = L.Conv2D(512, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv6)
    conv6 = L.Conv2D(512, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv6)
    conv6 = L.Dropout(0.4)(conv6)

    up7 = L.Conv2DTranspose(256, 2, strides=2, kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(conv6)
    conv7 = L.Concatenate()([up7, conv3])
    conv7 = L.Conv2D(256, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv7)
    conv7 = L.Conv2D(256, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv7)
    conv7 = L.Dropout(0.3)(conv7)

    up8 = L.Conv2DTranspose(128, 2, strides=2, kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(conv7)
    conv8 = L.Concatenate()([up8, conv2])
    conv8 = L.Conv2D(128, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv8)
    conv8 = L.Conv2D(128, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv8)
    conv8 = L.Dropout(0.2)(conv8)

    up9 = L.Conv2DTranspose(64, 2, strides=2, kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(conv8)
    conv9 = L.Concatenate()([up9, conv1])
    conv9 = L.Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv9)
    conv9 = L.Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv9)
    conv9 = L.Dropout(0.1)(conv9)

    c10 = L.Conv2D(n_classes, 1, activation='softmax', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv9)

    # Mimic crossentropy loss
    c11 = L.Lambda(lambda x: x / tf.reduce_sum(x, len(x.get_shape()) - 1, True))(c10)
    c11 = L.Lambda(lambda x: tf.clip_by_value(x, _epsilon, 1. - _epsilon))(c11)
    c11 = L.Lambda(lambda x: K.log(x))(c11)
    weighted_sm = L.multiply([c11, weight_ip])

    model = Model(inputs=[ip, weight_ip], outputs=[weighted_sm])
    return model
```

I then compile and fit the model as is shown below:

```py
model = make_weighted_loss_unet((256, 256, 3), 1) # shape of input, number of classes
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=my_loss, metrics=['acc'])
model.fit([x_train_val, y_weights], y_train_val, validation_split=0.1, epochs=1)
```

The model can then train as usual. However, the loss doesn't seem to improve much. Furthermore, when I try to predict on new images, I obviously don't have the weight maps (because they are calculated on the labeled masks). I tried to use empty / zero arrays shaped like the weight map but that only yields in blank / zero predictions. I also tried different metrics and more standards losses without any success.

Did anyone face the same issue or have an alternative in implementing this weighted loss? Thanks in advance. BBQuercus

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## A simpler way to write custom loss with pixel weights

In your code, the loss is scattered around, between `my_loss` and `make_weighted_loss_unet` functions. You can add targets as an input and use `model.add_loss` to structure the code better :

```
def make_weighted_loss_unet(input_shape, n_classes):
    ip = L.Input(shape=input_shape)
    weight_ip = L.Input(shape=input_shape[:2] + (n_classes,))
    targets   = L.input(shape=input_shape[:2] + (n_classes,))
    # .... rest of your model definition code ...

    c10 = L.Conv2D(n_classes, 1, activation='softmax', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv9)
    model.add_loss(pixel_weighted_cross_entropy(weights_ip, targets, c10))
    # .... return Model .... NO NEED to specify loss in model.compile

def pixel_weighted_cross_entropy(weights, targets, predictions)
    loss_val = keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy(targets, predictions)
    weighted_loss_val = weights * loss_val
    return K.mean(weighted_loss_val)
```

If you don't refactor your code to the above approach, next section shows how to still run inference without issues

## How to run your model in inference

### Option 1 : Use another `Model` object for inference

You can create a `Model` used for training and another used for inference. Both are largely the same except that the inference `Model` does not take `weights_ip`, and gives an early output `c10`.

Here's an example code that adds an argument `is_training=True` to decide which `Model` to return :

```
def make_weighted_loss_unet(input_shape, n_classes, is_training=True):
    ip = L.Input(shape=input_shape)

    conv1 = L.Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(ip)
    # .... rest of your model definition code ...
    c10 = L.Conv2D(n_classes, 1, activation='softmax', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv9)

    if is_training:
        # Mimic crossentropy loss
        c11 = L.Lambda(lambda x: x / tf.reduce_sum(x, len(x.get_shape()) - 1, True))(c10)
        c11 = L.Lambda(lambda x: tf.clip_by_value(x, _epsilon, 1. - _epsilon))(c11)
        c11 = L.Lambda(lambda x: K.log(x))(c11)
        weight_ip = L.Input(shape=input_shape[:2] + (n_classes,))
        weighted_sm = L.multiply([c11, weight_ip])
        return Model(inputs=[ip, weight_ip], outputs=[weighted_sm])
    else:
        return Model(inputs=[ip], outputs=[c10]) 
    return model
```

### Option 2 : Use `K.function`

If you don't want to mess with your Model definition method (`make_weighted_loss_unet`) and want to achieve the same result outside, you can use a function that extracts the subgraph relevant for inference.

In your inference function:

```
from keras import backend as K

model = make_weighted_loss_unet(input_shape, n_classes)
inference_function = K.function([model.get_layer("input_layer").input], 
                                [model.get_layer("output_softmax_layer").output])
predicted_heatmap = inference_function(new_image)
```

Note that you'll have to give `name=` to your `ip` layer and `c10` layer to be able to retrieve them via `model.get_layer(name)` :

```
ip = L.Input(shape=input_shape, name="input_layer")
```

and

```
c10 = L.Conv2D(n_classes, 1, activation='softmax', kernel_initializer='he_normal', name="output_softmax_layer")(conv9)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Beside this implementation of the pixel wise loss – would you recommend doing it this way or is there another, simpler way?

Comment: I tried training again. While I was able to predict something now (wohoo), the loss stayed constant and I just got blank predictions. Training with the same data just without the pixel wise loss shows a typical logarithmic decent in loss. Could that be due to a wrong loss function?

Comment: Regarding the activation/loss, I don't understand one thing. You have `y_train_val = (imgs, 256, 256, 1)` << has one channel, so your `n_classes=1`, right?. So c10 has 1 channel. I don't think Softmax is the activation that should be used here since it will output 1.0 for all pixels regardless of the value. You should use sigmoid instead.
Use Softmax for your binary classification IFF you have a vector output of length 2 (hot-one encoded vector for each pixel, for positive class vector=[1,0] and for negative=[0,1])

Comment: Yes, I just have positive / negative as my "classes". The model from the mentioned blogpost had a softmax activation. I'll give the sigmoid version instead. My main concern was that the loss function above doesn't calculate a weighted pixel wise loss

Comment: I'll try to train with your easier version. This makes a lot more sense code wise. Do I assume correctly that your `targets` input refers to the ground truth mask?

Comment: Yes, targets is the ground truth mask. You must still use Sigmoid OR use softmax and convert your targets/prediction to have 2 channels (one-hot). Note that the above is not tested, just shows the idea, so watch out for small errors

Comment: I'm having issues to train it – I assume you need a triple input (as list) of x_train, y_weights, and y_train. I get strange errors stating that it `Expected to see 1 array(s)`. The validation data would also be included somewhere?

Comment: I managed to get it training by adding `model = Model(inputs=[ip, weight_ip, targets], outputs=[output])` and having two models (one with loss and all three inputs, one with only the image input for inference). Training using `model.fit([x_train_val, y_weights, y_train_val],...`. I immediately get a loss function of either 0.000000.... or nan. Predictions work but as expected with such a loss I get nothing / blank.